# "or die()" in Python

Tags: python

Is anyone using anything like this in Python:

```
def die(error_message):
    raise Exception(error_message)

...

check_something() or die('Incorrect data')
```

I think this kind of style is used in PHP and Perl.

Do you find any (dis)advantages in this [style]?

Comment: what's wrong with `if` ?

Comment: It seems more logical to me that the `check_something` should be the function to raise the exception, rather than returning True/False. This would also allow for more useful error messages if there are many ways for a call to `check_something` to fail. Also, consider that your current implementation of `die` doesn't allow any Exception class besides the base Exception class to be raised, which seems rather limiting to me.

Comment: i don't use this now, but the idea came to me when stumbling upon `die()` in PHP. The code above is just an example of how `die` could be implemented.

Comment: what's wrong with `try:except:`?  "xxx() or die(reason)" is a too-cute-by-half legacy from Perl, *please* do not use it in any Python code.

Comment: just shorter, nothing wrong. wanted to know people's opinions.

Comment: raise Exception("description")

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Well, first, [`sys.exit([arg])`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit) is more common, and if you really wanted something equivalent to `die` in PHP, you should use that, raise a [SystemExit](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit) error, or call [os._exit](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os._exit).

The major use of the `die` method in PHP is, "The script has reached some impasse cannot recover from it". It is rarely, if ever, used on production code. You are better off raising an exception in a called function, catching it in the parent, and finding a graceful exit point -- that is the best way in both languages.

Comment: Wish I could +1 this one twice.  A developer who sees "die" in source code might reasonably expect that the attempt to die not be catchable; therefore if die() should be implemented at all it should call os._exit(1).

Comment: Well, `die` is catchable in Perl (though not PHP).

Comment: ... You can catch death in Perl... That is awesome. (Not trying to start a flame war, I just think that hilarious)

Comment: Not sure I want to catch death -- I hope its not contagious :-)

Comment: For what it's worth calling '''die''' is the standard way to raise an exception in Perl 5. The '''... or die ...''' expression in Perl is turning the non-fatal returning of an error into a catchable exception. In general you don't write this in Python as Python defaults to raising exceptions everywhere.

Answer (score 51):

Lot's of good answers, but no-one has yet suggested the obvious way to write this in Python:

```
assert check_something(), "Incorrect data"
```

Just be aware that it won't do the check if you turn on optimisation, not that anyone ever does.

Answer (score 27):

While that style is common in PHP and Perl, it's very un-Pythonic and I'd encourage you not to write Python that way. You should follow the conventions in the language you're using, and write something like this:

```
if not check_something():
    raise Exception('Incorrect data')
```

FWIW, doing the "or die(...)" way adds another level to your stack trace, which is another minor disadvantage.

Comment: Late remark, but sadly still valid: There is still no builtin method to raise exceptions in "exhaustive matching" scenarios like `direction = "left" if dir_id == 0 else "right" if dir_id == 1 else die("Invalid direction id", dir_id)`. This still requires defining some sort of `die` or `raise_` function.

Answer (score 7):

The biggest disadvantage is that all dying is now the same. Better to have `check_something()` raise a more accurate exception and then catch that up above if appropriate.

Comment: `All dying is now the same` definitely needs to be elaborated on. Sometimes you need simply need your program to just `die!` right then and there, without worrying about error handling.

Comment: If there is more than one way that `check_something()` can fail and return False, the `die()` function will always just throw an Exception that says _Incorrect data_ ... You don't want that: if there are two ways that the function could fail, you want to be able to tell the difference and fix accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

If you are dealing with an API that you didn't write that returns truthy values on success and falsy values on failure, that seems like a reasonably readable and compact way to do it.  If you have control over the API, I'd encourage you to use exceptions instead of return values to indicate errors.

If you use the function, it probably should not be called `die()` unless it actually exits the program, however. If it merely raises an exception, there's no guarantee that the program will actually die. Ideally you could name it `raise()` as a functional version of the `raise` statement, but of course you can't because `raise` is a reserved word. Perhaps `throw()`.

It would also be a good idea to require the caller to pass in an exception type, since `Exception` is rather generic and vague.

It occurs to me that this function would be unnecessary if only Python exceptions were capable of raising themselves, i.e., they had a method for it, like so:

```
class BaseException(object):
     def throw(self):
         raise self
```

Then you could just do:

```
check_something() or Exception("check failed").throw()
```

Sadly, Python exceptions can't raise themselves.  :-)

Comment: I chose `die` name to show where the idea comes from. I thought also to call it `raise_`. Interesting idea about `Exception.raise()`.

Comment: `Sadly, Python exceptions can't raise themselves.` You know what they say... it takes a village.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would want to **die**/**panic** with a helpful stack-trace so that you can easily locate the issue.
Hence, unlike the most popular answer, you should **AVOID** [sys.exit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) or raise a [SystemExit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) because they will cause your program to **die silently**(without a helpful trace).

You should use a general exception like [RuntimeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeError) that is most likely not going to be handled/caught later, and it will create a beautiful stack-trace:

```py
def die(message):
    raise RuntimeError(message)


print("hello world")
die('A helpful message')
print("hello world again")
```

We get the following helpful stack trace:

```
hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    die("A helpful message")
  File "/test.py", line 5, in die
    raise RuntimeError(message)
RuntimeError: A helpful message
```

If I had used `sys.exit` instead, I would have gotten the following **poor** output:

```
import sys

def die(message):
    sys.exit(message) # internally raises SystemExit

print("hello world")
die("A helpful message")
print("hello world again")
```

```
hello world
A helpful message
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are just wrapping php lingo in python with a one line function.  I would advise against it as you might confuse your audience.  Exceptions are also a completely different beast than die in PHP.